# How exactly typedef works here in template metaprogram?

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, template-meta-programming

I am new to template metaprogramming. While studying it, I came across this small code block which decides the type at compile time. My question is, how this typedef works in here. What exactly the sequence of program execution?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <bool condition, class Then, class Else>
struct IF
{
    typedef Then RET;
};

template <class Then, class Else>
struct IF<false, Then, Else>
{
    typedef Else RET;
};


int main()
{
    // if sizeof(int) < sizeof(long) then use long else use int
    IF< sizeof(int)<sizeof(long), long, int >::RET  i;

    cout << i << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well... technically you have undefined behavior because you never initialized `i`. ;)

Comment: @cdhowie Actually the statement before `i` does that! I believe

Comment: No, it does not.  `i` will have the type `long` and will be uninitialized.  Then you try to write the value of `i`, resulting in UB.

Comment: @cdhowie Ahha! It's definition, not initialization. But anyway, that's not the topic here. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typedefs are simply aliases for other types. Somehow the template needs a way of relaying a type to the user, so it creates a public `typedef` member in each of its specializations depending on the truth of the condition.

This is your primary template:

```c++
template<bool condition, class Then, class Else>
struct IF;
```

`IF` will always take take three parameters. The first, a non-type template boolean parameter, and the two types (`Then` and `Else`) that will be "returned" by the template depending on the truth of `condition`.

What follows is called a specialization:

```c++
template <class Then, class Else>
struct IF<false, Then, Else>;
```

To be more specific, this is referred to as a *partial* specialization because you're not specializing each template parameter. If you were the template parameter list (the things between the brackets in `template<...>`) would be empty. That is what is known as an *explicit* specialization.

---

Anyway, when you instantiate your template, it tries to choose the best specialization based on the given parameters. If one template is more specialized than the other, that template is chosen. Your primary template acts as a "default" template in that if the partially specialized template is not viable (meaning `condition` is not `true`) it falls back to the primary template and that is the one that is chosen. So in this case it acts as a template for the false condition. You could even specialize based on `false` instead of `true` in the partial specialization, in which case the roles of the templates are switched.

Since `sizeof(int)<sizeof(long)` is true on my platform, `IF` is instantiated in the following way:

```c++
IF<true, long, int>
```

This matches exactly with the partial specialization, so that one is chosen.

Inside the partial specialization there is a public member type definition called `RET` that aliases the second type parameter provided. Likewise, the first template aliases the first type parameter.

`RET` is accessed through the template and the type that it aliases is `int`. So what your code is equivalent to `i` being declared as an `int`:

```c++
int i;
```

And if `condition` was false, the primary template would be instantiated and `RET` would be `long`, which would make `i`'s type `long` as well.

Answer (score 0):

These `typedef`s are creating aliases for template argument types `Then` and `Else`.

Expression `IF<sizeof(int)<sizeof(long), long, int >::RET  i;` during compile time is evaluated in the following way.

1. Name Lookup, matches name identifier `IF` with `struct IF`.
2. Deduction of the template arguments for `template struct IF`.
3. Template specializations are first class citizens, so the compiler checks first if template arguments deducted match any of the specializations of `template struct IF`. If `sizeof(int) < sizeof(long)` evaluates to `false` the specialization `template <class Then, class Else> struct IF<false, Then, Else>` matches, so specialization of `template struct IF` is instantiated and `IF::RET` evaluates/aliases to `int` since in the specializaton of `template struct IF` `RET` aliases the second template argument (i.e., `Else`). If `sizeof(int) < sizeof(long)` evaluates to `true` specialization doesn't match and original `template class IF` is instantiated. In the former case `IF::RET` evaluates/aliases `long` since in the original template `RET` aliases the first template argument (i.e., `Then`).